# How to set the Slider value as NSTimeInterval for a Timer: iOS

Tags: ios, timer, uislider

I like to set the interval of a timer with an UISlider. I already have the value and the value as string, now I have to assign the value to the timer. Can someone please help me?

```
slidervaluefortimer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",slider.value];
```

Comment: You can use the float value you get from the slider to pass to the time interval argument of the timer creation method. Why are you converting it to a string?

Comment: @rdelmar I thought i have to convert it to an string. Can you please write down some code as answer, I dont get what you mean

Comment: slider.value returns a float (or double - not sure right now). NSTimeInterval actually is of type double. All you need to do is use that value directly, no explicit conversion/typecasting needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use the slider.value as the argument for this method:

```
NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:slider.value target:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```